# How to override `Shipping method` in `Edit Order` area?

Tags: magento-1

I am trying to override the shipping method in the `Edit order` area of the admin side.

What I have done is, added new file

`My/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Create/Shipping/Method/Form/Form.php` in my custom module. It has code,

```
<?php
class My_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Create_Shipping_Method_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Shipping_Method_Form
{
    protected function _toHtml(){
        $this->setTemplate('module/form.phtml');
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
}
?>
```

and in my `config.xml` ,

```
<blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite><sales_order_create_shipping_method_form>My_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Create_Shipping_Method_Form</sales_order_create_shipping_method_form>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
     </blocks>
```

in `frontend/adminhtml/default/default/template/module/form.phtml`

I wrote

`<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>`

I think this is enough to override the `sales_order_create_shipping_method_form`. But Unfortunately, nothing happens!! Please let me know If i missed something.

Comment: "in frontend/adminhtml/default/default/template/module/form.html"

This should be .phtml. Probably just a typo in your post though

Comment: yes. it was a typo in my post :)

Answer (score 1):

You have one excessive directory in a path to your block:

> My/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Create/Shipping/Method/<s>Form/</s>Form.php

What I really can't understand is by to rewrite a block when you can observe `adminhtml_block_html_before` event instead.